# changing sheet with macro causes sheet to freeze

Tags: vba, excel

My macro for changing sheets doesn't work anymore after I created a few UserForms. Thought the problem was the UserForms were not unloading properly but that doesn't seem to be the case.

When I click the button (which resides in a custom pop up menu) to go to another sheet it works but the sheet acts frozen, I can't scroll or highlight for example.

But if i change sheets by clicking on the tabs then everything is fine. So it would appear that my code to active another sheet is faulty.

My excel workbook has some `UserForms`, `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events if that matters.

**Is there a better way of doing this. Something that will obviously work and note freeze my sheet after it is activated?**

> Sheet goto Code:

```
Sub goto630()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

sht3.Activate
sht3.Protect _
        DrawingObjects:=False, _
        Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=False, _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True

sht2.Visible = True
sht3.Visible = True

On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    sht3.DisplayPageBreaks = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6).Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(8).Visible = False

Set sht2 = Nothing
Set sht3 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

> UserForm Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Finish"
    Unload Me
    Call Module2.ScreenRefresh
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

ScreenRefresh Module is just `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` read somewhere about this same problem that if the ScreenUpdating is in another module then when called it will fix the freeze issue.

Finish Module is activating the sheet again after the UserForm has been closed (also said to help the freeze issue).

**It seems that Excel is waiting for me to click a cell before allowing me to scroll. How can I get around this?**

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: It seems you can do this a lot easier. `Call Module2.ScreenRefresh` is after `Unload Me` it may or may not be executed so I would not do that. And you are doing something that can be achieve by assigning a macro to a shape. Shapes will never fail if you change the version of Excel etc, but active x and form controls may fail. If you explain what exactly you are trying to do, it is easy to show you a better practice

Comment: Excel probably isn't actually frozen; you can check the CPU usage in Task Manager to confirm. You are just leaving Application.ScreenUpdating in a False state.

Comment: @ Jeeped Yeah, Excel seems as if its frozen but i know its not. All of my code ends with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`